# Why glutSolidSphere is empty inside?

Tags: opengl

I draw glutSolidSphere and then I cut it using glClipPlane.
The cut sphere looks empty inside, i.e. reflection comes from inner spherical surface.
I want a planar cross section of my sphere look like a solid disc, not a hole to an empty sphere.

Comment: Thats nothing `glClipPlane` can do for you. You will have to implement the cut and the closing of the cutted region yourself.

Comment: Are there some tricks with lighting to get it easier way?

Comment: No. Since there is no geometry at the cut you will always see the backfaces.